# How to map IP by iptables ?

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, namespace

I create a network namespace

In this namespace, I open a nginx

So for now, I can visit web server by 172.17.0.2

What I want to do is mapping this IP to 127.0.0.1

Lets say if I visit 127.0.0.1, I want to connect to web server (172.17.0.2)

I try to use iptables like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1  -p tcp --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to-destination  172.17.0.2:80

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to-destination  172.17.0.2:80
```

I still cannot visit 127.0.0.1 to connect nginx.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The rule should be placed in OUTPUT chain :

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1  -p tcp --dport 80 -j  DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:80`

Check out **Chapter 6. Traversing of tables and chains**

of "Iptables tutorial" http://rlworkman.net/howtos/iptables/iptables-tutorial.html

The following also makes it easy to determine what chains to use :

http://rlworkman.net/howtos/iptables/images/tables_traverse.jpg